# How to share contents(a variable) of a project with another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I learnt that class can be used to make variables global but the scope of this variable is restricted within the project. How can the scope of variable be increased to all projects? For example, how can an image defined in one project be used in other projects?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an image in a location which is in another project, then just give the physical path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reference on the other project. You can do that by adding all projects to one   "project solution" and create a reference from one project directly do another. Or you can build project A. You will get for example a file called ProjectA.dll. Now take that .dll file and create a reference from ProjectB on the ProjectA.dll. Remember that you have to mark all  objects, you would like to use within another project, within ProjectA as public.

Read more about references here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ez524kew.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still having problems adding the reference. I have projects named `windowsservice1` and `app1` under the solution. When I did Add Reference>Solution>Projects to either of the projects, I already had the project I wanted to reference listed there. For example I had app1.csproj listed when I added references for windowsservice1. But a dialog box showing 'Unable to reference to project app1` is displayed. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Make sure, both projects are .net projects and not something like native c++. And also make sure, that you don't do something like this: ProjectA references ProjectB while ProjectB references ProjectA.

Comment: Both are .net projects and I am only trying to make a single reference